# SQL returning various dates when selecting only min(date)

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

My database have tables for default fields and custom tables for custom fields. while the main table has a id the custom one have id_c (which is a foreign key from id).
My table ger01_gerenciamentocliente_contacts_c is made for 2 foreign key connections from contacts id and ger01... id
their relationship is contacts 1 - n ger01_gerenciamentocliente

I am getting the min per ger01_gerenciamentocliente but i need min(date) (from ger01) per contact id. How do i do it?

```
SELECT T3.id, T0.MIN_MONTH FROM 
   (SELECT id_c, MIN(lftm_mes_referencia_c) as MIN_MONTH 
    FROM ger01_gerenciamentocliente_cstm GROUP BY id_c) T0 
INNER JOIN ger01_gerenciamentocliente T1 ON T0.id_c = T1.id AND T1.deleted = 0 
INNER JOIN ger01_gerenciamentocliente_contacts_c T2 ON T1.id = T2.ger01_gere60bccliente_idb AND T2.deleted = 0 
INNER JOIN contacts T3 ON T3.id = T2.ger01_gerenciamentocliente_contactscontacts_ida AND T3.deleted = 0 
WHERE T0.MIN_MONTH IS NOT NULL ORDER BY T3.id ASC;
```

Comment: You're doing a `GROUP BY`, so you'll get the min for _each_ group.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the sql a bit now it retrieves correctly

```
SELECT T3.id, MIN(T0.lftm_mes_referencia_c) as reference FROM 
ger01_gerenciamentocliente_cstm T0 
INNER JOIN ger01_gerenciamentocliente T1 ON T0.id_c = T1.id AND T1.deleted = 0 
INNER JOIN ger01_gerenciamentocliente_contacts_c T2 ON T1.id = T2.ger01_gere60bccliente_idb AND T2.deleted = 0 
INNER JOIN contacts T3 ON T3.id = T2.ger01_gerenciamentocliente_contactscontacts_ida AND T3.deleted = 0 
INNER JOIN contacts_cstm T4 ON T3.id = T4.id_c AND T4.deleted = 0
WHERE T0.lftm_mes_referencia_c IS NOT NULL GROUP BY T3.id;
```